# can read postgres database info...however cannot write into it

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sql-insert

I am using the following Node.js code.  It seems I can read my database however I am having an EXTREMELY difficult time writing into it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is unbelievably frustrating.

I have tried a number of variations on the INSERT SQL statement, all without success...I thank you in advance for any advice.

```
//**Query PostGres database...

const url = require('url')
var pg = require('pg');
const params = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
const auth = params.auth.split(':');

const config = {
user: auth[0],
password: auth[1],
host: params.hostname,
port: params.port,
database: params.pathname.split('/')[1],
ssl: false
};

var pool = new pg.Pool(config);
var conString = "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

const query = {
text: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1 AND cred = $2", 
values: [String(req.body.usr), String(req.body.pword)]
};

var written = "INSERT INTO users(name, cred, status, in, out, service, lucky) VALUES ?";
var writes = [String(req.body.usr), String(req.body.pword), 'active', 'test', 'pending', 'both', -1];


pool.connect(function(err,client,done) {
 if(err){
     console.log("not able to get connection "+ err);
     res.status(400).send(err);
 } 
client.query(query, function(err, result) {   
//call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
done(); 
 if(err){
 console.log(err);
 res.status(400).send(err);
 }

 if (typeof result.rows[0] === "undefined") {
 console.log("No user/password determined in DB for login attempt");
 } else {

  if (result.rows[0].status === "active") {
  console.log("User is determined to be ACTIVE in database");

   //...for WRITING into database...!
   client.query(written, [writes], function (err, result) {
   console.log("I am here now after writing);
   });

  } else {
  console.log("User is determined to be INACTIVE in database");
  }  //User ACTIVE...OR NOT...

 }  //user/password is 'undefined' (NOT found in database)...OR NOT 

 console.log(result.rows[0]);
 });
});
```

Comment: The `values` clause requires parentheses, `insert into (a,b,c) values (?,?,?)` You also specify 7 columns for the insert, but provide only one argument. I don't know JavaScript, but probably your insert should be defined as: `"INSERT INTO users(name, cred, status, in, out, service, lucky) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"`

Comment: When asking for help, always include the error message you get when running your code.

Comment: OK thank you for that I will try it out when I have a chance.  Actually I was not getting an error message...just not getting the desired values to write to the database.

Comment: I am still having immense problems.  I am using the following code:  const written = 'INSERT INTO users(name, cred, status, in, out, service, lucky) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING *';
const writes = [String(req.body.usr), String(req.body.pword), 'active', 'test', 'pending', 'both', -1];

Comment: client.query(written, writes, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log(res.rows[0])
    // { name: 'brianc', email: 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com' }
  }
})

Comment: error is:  syntax error at or near "in"   ...this code comes straight from the postgres online documentation.  Could the problem be caused by my variable definition for "in"...?  I set that up as a "character varying (20)" so therefore I do not believe so...?

Comment: I believe I found the error.  It seems I cannot use the word "in" for a column name in the database...likely a reserved word.  I deleted the table and created another using a different phrase and now it seems the INSERT command is behaving correctly.  Thanks for your response.